# IE change event does not trigger when click programmatically on file input

Tags: jquery, file, internet-explorer, input, onchange

I am clicking programmatically on an input type='file' and submit the file if input value is changed. It works properly in FF/Chrome (latest versions), but not in IE,

```
<input id='fileupload' type='file' visibility='hidden'>
<button id='TriggerUpload'>
<script>
    $("#fileupload").change(function() { alert('Value Changed'); } );
    $("#TriggerUpload").click( function() { $("#fileupload").click(); } );
<script>
```

Change event is not triggered in IE when click on input Browse button is done programmatically using another button click event, but works good when clicking directly on input Browse button (if visible)!

I tried using onpropertychange as explained in http://jsfiddle.net/7wR2L/14/ but it does not solve the problem in IE11!

Any suggestions and/or solution are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a very frustrating issue - I think its a bug in IE. Try this work around, basically forcing focus on your button:

```
$("#TriggerUpload").click( function() { 
   $(this).focus();
   $("#fileupload").click(); 
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you triggering the correct event?  You've subscribed to `change`, but are triggering `click`.  Instead:

```
$("#fileupload").change(function() { alert('Value Changed'); } );
$("#TriggerUpload").click( function() { $("#fileupload").trigger('change'); } );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/7wR2L/1350/ (I actually can't test this in IE...)